# How do I setup permissions on OpenCart files for www-data group AND 3 different terminal users to be able to mutually edit?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a new OpenCart website.  I and 2 different programmers with 3 separate logins need to edit the same OpenCart file base in the group www-data.  I have set the permissions using the instructions below.  But these instructions do not account for the 3 different users having permission to edit the files.  Do I need to make all the users members of the www-data group?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
//change user and group
chown -R wyattjackson:www-data 

//folds
find /path/to/opencart/root -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

//files
find /path/to/opencart/root -type f -exec chmod 744 {} +

chmod 775 image
chmod 775 system/storage
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with opencart (and don't know if it's files need to have an executable flag set), but you're almost there.  I'd suggest `find /path/to/opencart/root -type d -exec chmod ug=rwxt,o=rx {} +` and `find /path/to/opencart/root -type f -exec chmod ug=rwx,o=r {} +` ... these will ensure that anyone in the www-data group (assuming that's you and the other guys) can read/write the files. It might be even smarter to change ownerships to www-data:<newDevGrp> ...

Answer (score 0):

First, to ensure that the apache user creates files that are group writeable, you can change the default `umask` of the apache user by adding the following to either **/etc/apache2/envvars** (Debian/Ubuntu) or **/etc/sysconfig/httpd** (CentOS/Red Hat):

```
umask 002
```

Now you can either simply add everyone to the `www-data` group or…

1. Create a new group
2. Add everyone (including `www-data`) to it
3. Set the group ownership of the docroot to the newly created group
4. Set the `setgid` bit on the directory so that all files will inherit it's group: `chmod g+s /path/to/opencart/root`

The benefit of the second, slightly more complex approach is that you aren't opening up *all* of the files created by www-data to anyone in that group, thereby giving you a bit more granular control over your server permissions.